# Unique solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If I have the function $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with

$ f'(t) = k \cdot f(t) $

how can I argue that this solution has to be of the form $f(t) = Ce^{kt} $  and can't look any different?

Edit: Edit solution thanks to David

Comment: Differentiate $g(x)=e^{-kx}f(x)$.

Comment: @DavidMitra this is not working

Comment: 0 is a trivial solution. Suppose that $f\not\equiv 0$ then finish with the answer above.

Comment: The solution has the form $f(t)= C e^{kt}$, not what you wrote in your post.

Comment: @DavidMitra okay thanks I added that. Then your ofc right with the constant solution.

Comment: If you follow my first comment, you'll discover $g'(x)$ is identically $0$. Thus $g(x)$ is a constant function, and the desired result is one step away.

Comment: @DavidMitra Nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose
$f(x)=\frac{f(x)}{e^{kx}}e^{kx}=g(x)e^{kx}$ 
is any solution. Then by insertion:

$g'(x)e^{kx}+kg(x)e^{kx}=kg(x)e^{kx}$

$g'(x)=0$

$g(x)=C$

Hence

$f(x)=Ce^{kx}$

Comment: So good :). Thank you. Its so amazing!! You don't need any Theorem nor the complicated integral with ln nor any assumtions that f is non zero everywhere :)!

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{d(f(t))}{f(t)}=kdt\\
\implies \int\dfrac{d(f(t))}{f(t)}=\int kdt\\
\implies \ln|f(t)|=kt+C\\
\implies f(t)=e^{kt}e^C=C_1e^{kt}$$
The above construction forbids any other solution in the nonzero real numbers.

Comment: I just noticed by your proof that 'f=0' is also a solution. But thanks!

Comment: @Adam It can be. If so, then your question is itself wrong. Please check it to make sure that it is ``nonzero real numbers''.

Comment: I know that $f(0) \neq 0$ but I am not sure if it has any other zero points. In this case the integral construction might not work?